# Adding Keyboard Shortcut to Self Created Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have created a chrome extension used for copying and saving links(in local storage). I want to add a keyboard shortcut to it which on pressing opens my extension  (example, ctrl+shift+o, etc..) but here: chrome://extensions/shortcuts , my extension is not visible and hence I can't add any shortcut to it. Can you suggest me a way so that I don't have to click on the extension icon, again and again, to open up my extension?

[image]

https://obie.ai/blog/how-to-add-and-remove-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-and-hotkeys-for-a-chrome-extension-in-5-seconds-flat/

Here in this link it's shown how to add a shortcut key to an extension
But probably this feature is only available for extensions available in the google store.
M asking for a way to add a shortcut for an extension which is created by me

This is my manifest.json part in case it's required{
"manifest_version": 3,
"version": "1.1",
"name": "Link Saving Tool",
"action":{
"default_popup": "index.html",
"default_icon": "icon.png"
},
"permissions": [ "tabs" ]
}

Comment: First, do you have developer mode on. Second, is it unpacked, and third, have you refreshed the extension?

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Developer mode on: Yes
Loaded Unpacked : Yes
Updated/refresed : Yes

Comment: Hrm... I really don't know.

Comment: okay no problem!